# how to solve Memory leak in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing one application in Silverlight for windows phone 7. I am stuck in very common issues which comes in windows phone app however not able to get out of it in any ways. It is memory leak issue which comes during navigation from first page to second, second to first and so on for multiple times.

To solve it, i create one new project having 2 blank pages. Each page has 2 text blocks to print current memory and peak memory and one button to move to next or previous page. When navigate from page 1 to page 2, i make null referance of all 3 things and call gc.collect to destroy the page referance. Same way, while moving from page 2 to page 1, i do the same thing.

I also tried to call gc.collect() in timer for every 500 mili seconds, but still no result. If i remove gc.collect() totally, memory increases in MB so i think it is a must thing.

Comment: code is a wonderful thing...

Comment: I do not know how you do navigation, but my understanding that frame keeps pages in memory to support back navigation.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong. If you're continuously navigating from page 1 to page 2 then to page 1 again, you're keeping all the previous page instances in the navigation stack. It's bad for the memory management problems you've pointed out, but it's also awful UX as the user will have to press the back button a great deal of times before exiting the app (actually, I'm not even sure it would get past through marketplace certification).

After navigating to page 2, if you want to go to page 1 you need to call `NavigationService.GoBack` rather than `NavigationService.Navigate`. It will restore the previously cached instance of page 1 (so obviously you mustn't nullify the references on that page).

On some rare conditions, you might really want to navigate to a new instance of Page 1 instead of the previous one. In that case, call `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry` to remove the latest cached page from the navigation stack (you can call that multiple times to clear the entire stack).

Comment: Actually it is my requirement in app to navigate to new instance of page and on each and every page, I am using "NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry" but still not getting desired result. My requirement is to totally clean prev page before I navigate to anorher page because each and every page in my app is adding too much memory in the current memory stack and then goes beyond 140 MB. That's why I need to clean prev page memory.

Comment: @ashish123 `RemoveBackEntry` should be enough to remove the previous page from the memory. If it doesn't, then it means you have another kind of memory leak. Are you dynamically loading pictures or something like that in Page1?

Comment: @KooKiz, it's all what he need. Very helpful post. +1

Comment: @ashish123 Do you have any events being added on entry to one of the pages? Even on an object in the page? If you do, and aren't unregistering it, it will keep the page fully in memory.

Comment: But what if i'd remove a stack? Say, i have a MainPivot, and some subpages, and on one page (say, after login), i'm navigating to new instance of MainPivot. But in OnNavigatedTo(), i have while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null) ; Wouldn't be a first page collected?

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko If you remove a page from the backstack then it should be collected, yes

Comment: Is there a way to check all unsubscribed references? Something like GC.WhyWouldntYouCollectThisInstance(object instance)? I guess, i have a freaking leak here.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko Welcome to Windows Phone! You can track the references using the profiler, but it'll show you only the managed objects. If you're leaking native memory then the only way to find the source is trial and error. Also, I've noticed a surprising behavior, haven't found the time to write an article about it: pages are collected only after the third passage of garbage collector. So, to test the memory, create a button, call `GC.Collect` when tapped, and tap it three times. If after the third time the memory still hasn't been collected then you have indeed a leak

Comment: Note that calling `GC.Collect` directly three times won't work, it would be too easy. You have to let the UI thread do some stuff in-between, that's why it's working well with a button. You can achieve the same behavior by using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to delay each of your three calls to `GC.Collect`. Please tell me if it has an impact on your problem.

Comment: I know, that i have a leak: in my scenario with MainPivot, i have Debug.WriteLine("!!!" + GetHashCode()); inside of PivotControl_OnSelectionChanged. And after i return to MainPivot, using forward navigation, i got several hashcodes in output. So the target is to find, where is referense, which makes Pivot uncollected.

Comment: And yes, just run a profile. It shows that i'm using about 40 Mbs, but only 1 Mb of managed memory. Crap ><

Comment: Actually, i'm considering using NonLinearNavigationService, but it seems to be like a hack, not like real solution.

Comment: Tried exactly as you said: added appbutton with CG.Collect in command. So, now i know, i definitely have a leak. However, i have no idea, what can be a source of a leak: o have only pivot with 1 pivotItem and Cimbalino appbar. Also, i'm playing with NonCircularNaviService, but i still have 2 instances of one view.